# GWT page is not loaded correctly on IE8 on first access

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a strange problem when loading my app on IE8: on the first page load, the application is loaded, but nothing is shown on page (blank page). The strange thing is that when i move the mouse over textbox or links, the cursor changes, seaming that every element is invisible.
If i hit refresh, the page is drawn correctly. I have tested on a windows XP, on virtual machine, IE8.
On IE9 also works fine.

This issue appears in the compiled code (production mode). I believe that the problem is a the code size: the initial download is 700KB, and then another fragment is downloaded (800KB), although the page is not visible at all after the initial donwload.

EDIT:
I just made a few tests: i cleared the onModuleLoad method and added just a label and a text box. They are being displayed correctly. So doesn't that mean that there is no problem with the settings (html or .gwt.xml file)?

Comment: I think the problem is with your doctype (because I had a similar problem once). Because GWT layout system correctly works only in standards mode. Set the doctype in HTML pages to <!DOCTYPE html> which is the standards mode

Comment: That's not the problem, I already had <!doctype html> into my html file. I tried with lowercase, and no [\n] (Enter) character at the beginning of the file, it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is this in dev mode, or the compiled code?

Comment: This happens in compiled code.

Comment: Is it possible to post your .html page?

Comment: I could post a part of it... What part would you like to examine ?

Comment: I won't know the problem till I see it.  I was hoping to look it over and see if anything stood out that would cause your problem.  I don't think your problem is in the code size because I have seen apps that have 6M of js to download.  Have you checked the developer console after the first page load to see if there were any errors?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29900/discussion-between-ice13ill-and-deanna)

Comment: I could send you the file by email. Btw, I don't believe that the problem is with any errors in the code because the page is rendered and the script runs as usual - the elements are not visible but i can interact with them (mouse cursor changes on hover, links can be clicked)... it's like everything has opacity 0. If i refresh the page (ie. after the code has been cached, everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by including at least one  tag for my stylesheets. All of my css files were loaded in my .gwt.xml module, none in the base html file. So, it's a very strange workaround for IE8 where the page is displayed blank (at the first load) if it doesn't contain any css  tag in the html file.